# How to execute this Python terminal base64 encoder code in my script?

Tags: python, base64

I´m new to Python programming and I´m working on a script to encode and decode base64.

I found and test this example that is executed directly on the Python terminal

```
>>> import base64

>>> encoded = base64.b64encode(b'data to be encoded')

>>> encoded

b'ZGF0YSB0byBiZSBlbmNvZGVk

>>> data = base64.b64decode(encoded)

>>> data

b'data to be encoded'
```

But when I use this same code directly on my script it doesn´t work and I don´t clearly understand where the problem is.

This is my script

```
import base64

encoded = base64.b64decode('S1JZUFRPTklTR1JFQVQ=')

print(encoded)
```

This is the error I recieve when running it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "base64.py", line 1, in <module>
import base64
File "C:\Users\Charles\Desktop\Python\base64.py", line 3, in <module>
encoded = base64.b64encode(b'data to be encoded')
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'base64' has no attribute 'b64encode' (most likely due    to a circular import)
```

The same case occurs when trying to execute the decoder.

I don´t totally understand what the 'b between the parenthesis does, but I don´t think it cause any problem.

Comment: You called your script file `base64.py`. Rename your fie.

Comment: To add to what @Daniel said.
You named your file the same thing as an existing python extension.
When you call 
`import base64.py`
You actually imported your own script because that's what you named it "base64".

Comment: when you import files in python it'll check the path where you ran the script from for modules with that name first, then it'll check the core library and your downloaded libraries. In general try to be careful to not name your python files the same as existing modules.